# Flutter - border parameter isn't defined

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to style a `TextField` in Flutter using the `InputDecoration` class.

Here is the [implementation](https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/text-input/)-

```
new TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none, // The named parameter border isn't defined
    hintText: 'Please enter a search term'
  ),
);
```

But this results in a red squiggly line underneath border property with message

`The parameter border isn't defined`

Rest properties are working fine. Here is the screenshot of same -
[image: border]
PS - I'm new to Flutter.

Comment: Your code looks good. Does the Dart analyzer show other errors?

Comment: No just this one @GünterZöchbauer.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the IDE?

Comment: Yes, I even tried `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: What Flutter version are you using.

Comment: Flutter 0.0.22-pre.1 • channel alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on v0.0.22 of Flutter which is many months old. I found [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/13734) from around the same time which says:

> What was called the "divider" is now a configurable border

So my guess is that maybe the version you're using didn't have `border`.

You should switch to the beta channel (`flutter channel beta`) to try again with more recent code.

Comment: That worked. After changing to beta channel it detected `border`